# Command "make:datatable" is not defined

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-livewire

https://github.com/rappasoft/laravel-livewire-tables
I have installed the package via composer and when I try to use the make:datatable command to create a data table, I get the error Command "make:datatable" is not defined. ' It would be of great help if someone could help me out. Thank you.[image]

https://github.com/rappasoft/laravel-livewire-tables

Comment: Which version did you install? From https://rappasoft.github.io/laravel-livewire-tables-docs/start/Commands: "_This feature is available in v1.12 and above_"

Comment: I just used this command to install it "composer require rappasoft/laravel-livewire-tables". I will try to find the version and reply again

Comment: Hey, Do you know how to update the php? I think this might be the problem. I have version 7.3.11 and it needs it to be 7.4. I tried installing xampp with php version 8 and it still won't recognise it.

Answer (score -2):

You try update your version of php, that corrected my problems at least is 7.4, for the commands

Answer (score -2):

I installed the package via composer and in my composer.json the installed version was 0.4.0 .

I noticed that in the docs there is a note: **This feature is available in v1.12 and above** .

I changed the version directly in my composer.json to ^1.21 (this is the latest version at the moment) and then just run update composer and it worked.

Comment: I'd recommend you to try https://github.com/Power-Components/livewire-powergrid, it's very simple to use